# Sideways Figure flushed to the left side of page with text running down the right hand side

Tags: floats, sidewaysfigure, figure-placement

I have been trying to figure out how to achieve this for some time but seemt to be completely stuck. I have a figure (as shown below) that i have made sideways due to the style of the figure. My hope is to have the figure flush to the left side of the page, and have the text continue down the right hand side of the page to make the best use of the page, however i dont seemt o be able to work out how to achieve this. The code that i am currently using on overleaf is:

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=0.4\textheight]{Figures/Feature Selection/hierarchial_clustering_featureVectors.pdf}
\caption{{\bfseries Hierarchial clustering of the feature vectors} } \label{fig:FeatureVectorHierarchialClustering}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

Which has got me to this point:

[image]

Any help / things to try would be massively benefical as i coulddnt seem to find this question on the site currently in any variation that helped my situation.

Update:

If i change the width=\textwidth to width=0.5\textwidth then it will produce this output:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ. Incidentally, by setting `width=\textwidth`, you're assuring that no space will be available for text down the right-hand side of the (rotated) page. Please clarify the purpose of `width=\textwidth`.

Comment: The document class i am using is article, and the purpose of including the width=\textwidth was to make the figure take the full length of the page. For example if i set the width=0.5\textwidth it will create this format of figure. I will edit the main question to clarify this point! I think because it is a rotated figure, the textwidth becomes the height and then the textheight is now the width, hence the 0.4 on the textheight to allow room for the text down the right hand side.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272486/fit-sidewaysfigure-to-page-width-including-caption-and-source  Actually, one could simplify the given answer using `keepaspectratio` (new).